# how to store a graph in a data structure when there are multiple ways to traverse two nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, graph

I would like to store a directed graph consisting of nodes and edges to design an algorithm. In addition to the traditional setting, there are multiple ways to travel between nodes. Suppose I pick a pair of nodes namely `A` and `B`. I can go from `A` to `B` with a car or a truck. My goal is to find all possible paths given two nodes using breadth first search (BFS). I was wondering how I should store my dataset to code BFS efficiently.

In a traditional setting, I store my network in a `defaultdict` as I share below.

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self, nodeNumber):
        self.V = nodeNumber
        self.network= defaultdict(list)
    def edgeConstruct(self, i, j):
        self.network[i].append(j)
```

My question is what could be the best way to store my network if there are multiple ways to travel between every two nodes. My goal is to find all possible ways to go from one location to another using different way of travel methods.

```
A B "car"
A B "truck"
B C "car"
B C "bus"
B C "bicycle"
...
```

Comment: Do you mean that a possible path should use a unique travel method, or can you do one part with a car (then leave that car there) and continue by bicycle (which you had in the trunk of the car)? But can you then still do a third part with a car (which should be a different car?)

Comment: You can switch between travel methods meaning that you can from A to B by car and then go from B ro C by bus.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an edge per travel method, and specify that travel method as a label of the edge.

```
class Network:
    def __init__(self, nodeNumber):
        self.V = nodeNumber
        self.network= defaultdict(list)
    def edgeConstruct(self, i, j, travelmethod):
        self.network[i].append((j, travelmethod))
```

Comment: There is a slight problem with this setting. If I am trying to find how to get from A to C. There won't be a node called C. There will be multiple nodes saved as (C, car), (C, bus) etc. During the BFS, I need to give one source and one sink node into the algorithm.

Comment: If you can only give source and target in the algorithm, then that is a problem at the side of what you call "the algorithm", because that does not uniquely define the "way of travel". So if you are really tied to that, you'll have to duplicate nodes, and this can have exponential consequences. Better review that "algorithm".